# WiFi authentication and association is usually done by software or by hardware (meaning 802.11 MAC module or wireless NIC)?

Tags: authentication, associations, wifi

I'm studying 802.11 MAC and I get confused a little about association. Some sources say that WiFi MAC is doing association (in two modes - passive and active scanning, https://devopedia.org/wi-fi-mac-layer), but on the other hand, authentication is done usually by software (I think). So, my question how do these two processes interact with each other - 802.11 MAC on the station constantly tries to associate with whatever AP it can sense (with the strongest signal), but AP allows association only after successful authentication - are these correct or association is done in software too and 802.11 MAC has nothing to do with that?